# Multiple Horizontal List View

Tags: android, android-listview

In my activity, I have three horizontal list views. Each list view is different.

I'm having difficulty trying to get a certain layout to work: I want to have multiple lists on a page; each list does not have to be scrollable, but should be shown completely.

The page itself should be able to scroll (with the lists in it), if the total content is longer than the screen, like the [Allrecipes.com Dinner Spinner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.allrecipes.spinner.free) app.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Add your scrollviews to a listview. You can create a listadapter which returns your horizontal list views.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429
The rows would have your horizontal list views in them.

Comment: That will be harder since you are using view recycling horizontally. Have you tried placing them in just a scroll view? Please add what you have tried to the post.

Answer (score 0):

There is a view in android called **Recycler View** . It's a reimplementation of the list-view in android with lots of new features. In Recycler view, you can easily make a horizontal list view. I have found a tutorial, The source code is included in the tutorial .

http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html